# Laravel 5.6 Entering date from the form and validate before saving into the database

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a form that allows users to enter date and submit

However, the validation rules somehow it looks like failing.

`'reportedDate'=>'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d'`

​
​ `<div class="form-group">
    <label for="reportedDate">Reported Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid':errors.reportedDate}" placeholder="2018-05-28" name="reportedDate" v-model="list.reportedDate">
    <small class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.vin_no"  >{{errors.reportedDate[0]}}</small>
</div>`

Comment: What is the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

From laravel docs

> The field under validation must match the given format. You should use either date or  date_format when validating a field, not **BOTH**.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

Comment: Thanks, I had a typo error. copy and paste is the problem